# MarketingCloudSDK-iOS | A few devices are not receiving push notifications. Which scenarios can cause the cancelled status?

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios, push-notification

We noticed that a few devices are not receiving push notifications on iOS.

We are using MarketingCloudSDK `8.1.0`. This is how we are configuring the SDK:

```
let configuration = PushConfigBuilder(appId: .appID)
            .setAccessToken(.accessToken)
            .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(appEndpoint)
            .setMid(.mid)
            .setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(true)
            .setAnalyticsEnabled(true)
            .build()

        let completionHandler: (OperationResult) -> () = { result in
            //Request notification permission; SFMCSdk.identity.setProfileId;
         }
    
    SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(ConfigBuilder().setPush(config: configuration, onCompletion: completionHandler).build())
```

In the devices we aren't receiving push notifications we log the state using `SFMCSdk.state()` and got this:

```
SDK State = {
  "modules" : {
    "cdp" : {
      "compatibility" : "2.0.2 - 2.9.9",
      "name" : "cdp",
      "pendingOperations" : "undefined",
      "status" : "inactive",
      "version" : "unavailable"
    },
    "push" : {
      "compatibility" : "8.1.0 - 8.9.9",
      "name" : "push",
      "pendingOperations" : "0",
      "status" : "cancelled",
      "version" : "unavailable"
    }
  },
  "registrationId" : "562B525E-8C71-4D8E-A51A-2501DFD5E843",
  "version" : "1.1.0"
}
```

We noticed that the push status is `cancelled`, we checked the documentation that says:

> //module initialization was cancelled (for example due to re-confirguration triggered before init was completed)

But we checked on code and either `SFMCSdk.initializeSdk` or any other configuration is being called before init was completed.

We also noticed that in these scenarios we can't find a `contact` with the returned `registrationId` on MarketingCloud platform (MobilePush).

**We trying to understand why some devices are not receiving push notifications. Is there any other scenarios that can cause the cancelled status?**